# Accessing Hive Tables with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I've setup an AWS EMR cluster that includes spark 2.3.2, hive 2.3.3, and hbase 1.4.7. How can I configure spark to access hive tables?

I've taken the following steps, but the result is the error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning when creating Hive client
> using classpath:
>
> Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are
> included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars

Steps:

1. `cp /usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /usr/lib/spark/conf`
2. In `/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` added:

   spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hive/lib/*
3. In zeppelin I create a spark session:

   val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("clue").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
   import spark.implicits._

Answer (score 0):

Step (1, & 2) you mentioned are partially fine, except for a little tweak that might help you.

Since you are using `hive-2.x`, configure `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars` and set it to `maven` instead and `spark.sql.hive.metastore.version` to match the version of your metastore `2.3.3`. It should be sufficient to just use `2.3` as version, see why in the [Apache Spark Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c65f9b2bc35c2926bb3658f65fe4f8a0b8e9fe4a/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/client/IsolatedClientLoader.scala#L103)

**Here is a sample of my working configuration that I set in `spark-default.conf`:**

```
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout  600 # An arbitrary number that you can change
spark.sql.catalogImplementation hive
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars   maven
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version    2.3  # No need for minor version
spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession   true
spark.sql.warehouse.dir {hdfs | s3 | etc}
hive.metastore.uris thrift://hive-host:9083
```

With the previous setup, I have been able to execute queries against my datawarehouse in Zeppelin as follow:

```
val rows = spark.sql("YOUR QUERY").show
```

More details for connecting to an external hive metastore can be found here ([Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/advanced/external-hive-metastore.html))

Comment: Is there any additional setup required for `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` aside from creating the directory location in HDFS/S3/etc? Also, prior to your post, in the `hive-site.xml` I copied to `spark/conf` I changed the execution engine to `mr`, but now encounter the error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormatBase`. Have you encountered jar dependency issues like this? Thanks.